# I am new to React hooks and trying this code for submitting the form. I am getting this error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With the below code i am able to save **userDetails** to the database but i am not getting the ***console.log(result.data)*** output.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    import axios from "axios";
    const AnotherForm = () => {
      const [fullName, setName] = useState();
      const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
      const [email, setEmail] = useState();
      const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    
      const onSubmitting = async (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(name);
        // console.log(userName);
        // console.log(email);
        // console.log(password);
        const UserDetails = { fullName, userName, email, password };
        const result = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/app/signup",
          UserDetails
        );
        try {
          console.log(result.data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
        console.log(result);
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        onSubmitting();
      }, []);
      return (
        <div className="form-div">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmitting}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Full Name"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control form-group"
            />
    
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="User name"
              onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control form-group"
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control form-group"
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPassword(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="form-control form-group"
            />
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default AnotherForm;
```

> I am getting this error in the browser's console

```
POST http://localhost:5000/app/signup net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:87
wrap @ bind.js:9
onSubmitting @ Another.file.forForm.withHooks.js:18
(anonymous) @ Another.file.forForm.withHooks.js:30
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:590
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:545
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

> I am also not able to use `e.preventDefault()` method inside my code, i am getting the below error. At present, `e.preventDefault()` is commented in the code.

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

The above are the two concerns with the code.

> *Do i need to use `preventDefault()` method in the above code* or is it okay to remove it!!

**Any help is appreciated**

Comment: Please check your network and try again

Comment: Network is working fine.

Comment: could you post a screen of what youre are getting as a response in network tab ( don't forget the payload aswell)